# looking for a succinct way to describe a book one can never grow tired of reading

Tags: phrase-requests

I am writing an essay. In my essay, I am describing how I have gained a new understanding of a book at different ages. At the end of my essay, I conclude this is a book one could never grow tired of reading.

This is the last paragraph of my essay:

"How many times could one read "One Hundred Years of Solitude"? It is a book of __"

A book of my lifetime? A book for life?

Comment: Why has the "long answers" automated response been added to this *question*? (+1 simply to offset this bizarre response.) And I filed [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330508/were-looking-for-long-answers-that-provide-some-explanation-and-context-was-a) about this on Meta.

Comment: By the way, if talking about books that people keep reading and discussing, would the word *classic* work?

Comment: Please [edit] this to give an example sentence you would like to use the phrase in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use the phrase : never gets old.

As in - that book never gets old.

*never gets old* -> something that you always find enjoyable and or interesting, never stops being fun.